# How to make Google Reader (or any RSS reader) get items from the NEW Digg.com?

Tags: google-reader, rss, digg

Since this morning (Aug-25 2010) Google Reader can't read the Digg RSS feed. Apparently, Digg.com underwent a major upgrade, and a lot of things had changed.

If I paste the URL `http://digg.com/news.rss` into a browser, I'm able to see the RSS it generates. But Google Reader says there's no feed available for this URL.

Does anyone know the new URL for the top news feed from Digg?

Comment: Start reading reddit... :P

Comment: Try that feed URL again

Answer (score 2):

http://services.digg.com/2.0/story.getTopNews?type=rss seems to work in Google Reader.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

### Yahoo Pipes

With [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/) you can build "pipes" that take input from a wide variety of sources and output it as RSS. You build them from interconnected boxes in a GUI.